# domain-taxonomy in D7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, domain-access

I installed domain-access module , 
 I want create some taxonomy and load it in one content type

I want show  per taxonomy only on same domain.

for example I have 2 vocabulary(Ubuntu and Arch)

if url is http://Ubuntu.project/node/add/ask . Ubuntu vocabulary is loaded,

else if url is http://Arch.project/node/add/ask . Arch vocabulary is loaded

please help me and thank you.